# How to use a video as a reference on a plane?

Tags: texturing, video

Can I use a video to texture a plane so I can use it as a reference for animating? It is important that I can view the texture without rendering the scene.

**Edit:** After loading an image as empty, I can't access the controls to Match Movie Length or Auto Refresh 
[image][image]!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsUcH.png)

Comment: Which render engine, cycles or internal

Comment: @PandaAB It seems to me that the MOV file in question is encoded with codec that blender (or the operating system) cannot deal with. Quicktime files can be compressed on a wide variety of formats and still be a MOV file, in other words: quicktime is just a wrapper. Blender cannot decode all flavors. It is also possible that the version of quiktime in your operating system is preventing you to use that file. In any case, try converting it into an image sequence. All the answers in this page still apply for image sequences.

Comment: I am using both render engines but is there a specific one i should be using.

Comment: I have tried many different files and it is not working so should I have the newest version or what?

Comment: Hey thanks guys for the help but i figured it out and all i had to do was download the newest version. It is kinda weird because i had the 2.68 version instead of the 2.71 version but yet there was that much difference. Thanks again.

Comment: You have to increase the amount of total frames in order for it to work. [![https://files.catbox.moe/59nf4i.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDssG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDssG.png)

Answer (score 14):

A different approach involves not using a plane at all but an [empty as an image:](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Empties)

[image]

Select the image in the properties->Empty->Display tab

[image]

Click on **match movie length** and enable **Auto Refresh**
You should see the number change in the Frames box on the left.

[image]

You'll get your image (or video) in an empty. The advantage of this method is that your image will be visible even in when the 3D viewport shading is set to wireframe or bounding box. Note that empties will not be rendered on the final render...
[image]

Comment: I did what you said but every thing under display doesn't show.

Comment: The options will be available once you have chosen an image (or video) where it says Open.

Comment: It worked but when i scroll down the timeline the video on the plane doesn't play. And Auto refresh is on.

Comment: Did you click on Match movie length?

Comment: @PandaAB what is the format of your video file?

Comment: It is .mov and every thing is not under display.

Comment: Could you post an image of what you get instead under display? Make sure that you are not looking at the "display" that has check boxes for Name, Axis, Bound etc, but the one for the image. Check the second picture within in my answer above, I added an arrow for the icon to look for.

Comment: I posted it up top because I'm not sure how to put in comments

Answer (score 5):

**Tha lazy way to do this**:

(Works for Cycles and Blender Render)

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to open the User Preferences and press on the Addons Tab.

Enable the "Import Images as Planes" addon[image]

In the 3D view press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and find Mesh->Images As Planes

[image]

Select the video you need. (Note that there are some options on the left for the texturing of the plane).
[image]

A plane will be created with the proportions of the imported video, UV unwrapped and already textured with the chosen image.

[image]

All that is left to do is enable **Auto Refresh** on the texture nodes so the video updates as you scroll down the time line.

[image]

NOTE: The texture on the Plane will be visible only when the shading in the 3D viewport is set to Textured, Material and Rendered.

[image]

Comment: I did this way but when i import the video it doesn't show on the plane.

Comment: Make sure the viewport shading is on Textured or Rendered.

Comment: It worked but when i scroll down the timeline the video on the plane doesn't play. And Auto refresh is on.

Comment: @PandaAB this is an bug on cycles, have you ever got it working?

Answer (score 3):

## Cycles

In cycles you'll have to put the video into the material nodes of your plane with an *Image texture* node.

1. Add your plane
2. UV Unwrap it (<kbd>U</kbd>)
3. Create a new material and add a texture node. Click *Open* and select your video file.
4. Enable *Auto refresh*.
5. Switch to textured view and ensure the image texture node is active (last selected).

Comment: You can also use a video file as texture, no need to convert to image sequence.

Comment: @cegaton Wow, never knew you could do that. Thanks :)

Comment: Depending on the codec used on the video file, you might still get better performance using Image Sequences though.

Answer (score 3):

### Blender Internal

1. Unwrap your plane
2. add an image texture.
3. Change the view mode to textured[image]
4. Hit <kbd>N</kbd> to open the tool bar, and under shading, change the type to GLSL
   [image]
5. In the texture properties, hit the Match Movie Length button.
6. Check auto refresh.
7. Set the Mapping to UV, and select your UV map.
   Here is a picture of the settings:

[image]