# Adding an image to a plane as a reference

Tags: image

I am modelling a mountain on the Moon using a reference photo from above. I have added a simple plane in top ortho view, and would really like to just plop that photo onto the plane.

I started looking into UV mapping, but it doesn't seem to be what I need, at least not the way it is usually used. I added the image as a reference, which helps a little, but of course as soon as I'm not in top ortho view, it disappears.

How would I do this?

Comment: You can also use an empty as image See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13897/1853

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing/314#314

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the addon **Import Images as Planes**, after installation go to File > Import > Images as Planes, and now you should choose the photo. It will be imported as plane. With out need of you Unwrapping it.

Comment: It's done it, but i can't see the image. I can't seem to find current documentation for the add-on.

Comment: Found it - you have to go to the N panel, and check the box next to Textured Solid under the Shading section.