# Image Object not showing up in render view?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, image

[image]

Doesn't show up, how would I fix this?

[image]

Comment: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490)

Comment: @cegaton yes the object is a "Empty" image.

Comment: Images as empty are not designed to render. They are used as reference only. Use an image as plane instead.

Comment: @cegaton how would I do this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35949/adding-an-image-to-a-plane-as-a-reference

Comment: @cegaton I've changed it to a background image and it's not appearing how do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Background image is not showing in the rendered slot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65212/the-background-image-is-not-showing-in-the-rendered-slot)