# The Video I assigned to a Material is not running, where is the problem?

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, video

[image]
I rendered a shadeless version of the Animation i made and want to now set it into the TV in my animation so that there is a 2D version of the same scene running in the TV. You can already see the grey shape of the anglerfish in the square TV dummy thing but it isnt moving when i go along the timeline and render. 
what i did was unwrap the UV map of the screen and assigned the video to the material that is the screen part. ive already tried "match movie length". Does anyone know where the problem could be?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105750/image-sequence-texture-no-preview ?

Comment: Enable auto refresh