# Image sequence bug?

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, node-editor, shaders

[image]

I've been trying to add an image sequence in the node editor to give my characters animated expressions, but when I change the offset the material turns pink, pls help

[image: Image Sequence node with higleited offset input field]

Comment: maybe you can't see any image with this offset value?

Comment: for some reason it only shows anything when in offset 9, and not anything else

Comment: in your node, Frames determine the number of frames that can be read in your series, Offset at what frame it is supposed to begin, Start Frame allows to freeze the first frame for the desired number of frames, is it correctly set?

Comment: Did you try checking the auto-refresh button?

Comment: And see this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105750/image-sequence-texture-no-preview

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)