# How to Create a Custom View

Tags: customization

You know how Blender has the numpad keyboard shortcuts to get to different views (e.g. Front, Side, Top, etc.)

I have some reference images that aren't from any of these perspectives. Is it possible to create a custom view axis so that I can have these references displayed from the correct perspective?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that what cameras are for?

Comment: You can use an [empty to display an image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13897/935) and align it however you want. You should get used to that as this appears our only option for reference images in 2.80

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Hey, yeah! I didn't think about using a camera!

Comment: @sambler Oh, interesting. Do you know why background images are going away in 2.8?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8