# How to add vfx footage to blender?

Tags: edit-mode, video

hello everyone  am curious as to how do I add my effects footage(as in I downloaded a video effects footage pack so I want to the video I want to edit)   to my video clip in blender

Comment: Use the Images as Planes Add-on. You might need to Mix in a Transparency Shader based on the movie Alpha. related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13888/how-to-use-a-video-as-a-reference-on-a-plane

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to add clip to Blender.
So if you are in:

### `2.79`

Go to the selection list and select Movie Clip editor.
[image]

and open your clip..
[image]

### `2.80`

Again go to the selection list and select Movie Clip editor. 
[image]

and open your clip..
[image]

Hope this helps.